# Wait for array to be populated before rendering EJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, ejs

I am trying to render two separate sets of data on an HTML page using EJS.  Currently, the "data" portion is rendering, but the "test" portion does not have time to push to the empty "test" array before it renders, and instead is giving me an empty array.

```
var test = []    
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    run(function(err, dat){
        res.render('index.ejs', { data: data, test: test})
    });
});

for (var i = 0; i < problems.length; i++) {
    var testing = problems[i].status;
    test.push(testing);
    //console.log(test)
}
```

Comment: Why not just move your `for` loop above the `app.get` section?

Comment: or you can put some time delay of 300ms

Comment: any manipulation on data from a request should be done after the request respond to a state of completeness. so basically, put your loop `for(){}` after wherever your array `problems` is getting its values.

Comment: first make sure that the problems array's length is not 0.